# Userwarning with GridSearchCV scoring and refit params

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using GridSearchCV for tuning my MNB model. However, I keep getting UserWarning when setting the GridSearchCV(scoring, refit) params. I've read the docs and other related StackOverflow questions over and over and followed the answers but still getting errors. It works when using only one metric though. I am having a hard time understanding what's wrong.

```py
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

parameters = {'alpha': [1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001]}
scorers = {
    "accuracy": make_scorer(accuracy_score),
    "precision": make_scorer(precision_score),
    "recall": make_scorer(recall_score),
    "f1_score": make_scorer(f1_score)
    }
mnb = MultinomialNB()
classifier = GridSearchCV(mnb, parameters, return_train_score=False, cv=10, scoring=scorers, refit='accuracy')
classifier.fit(x_train_features, y)
```

Error

```
 UserWarning,
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:774: UserWarning: Scoring failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 761, in _score
    scores = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py", line 103, in __call__
    score = scorer._score(cached_call, estimator, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py", line 264, in _score
    return self._sign * self._score_func(y_true, y_pred, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py", line 1765, in precision_score
    zero_division=zero_division,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py", line 1544, in precision_recall_fscore_support
    labels = _check_set_wise_labels(y_true, y_pred, average, labels, pos_label)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py", line 1357, in _check_set_wise_labels
    f"pos_label={pos_label} is not a valid label. It "
ValueError: pos_label=1 is not a valid label. It should be one of ['Negative', 'Positive']
```

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps you need to set `pos_label` (default is `1`) to either `"Negative"` or `"Positive"` in `precision_score` (and perhaps some other arguments too?).

Comment: I replaced my labels to Positive ->  1 and  Negative -> 0 and worked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to override the pos_label parameters using the above setup in the score metrics so I
replaced my dataset labels `Positive -> 1` and `Negative -> 0` instead.